# Creating a development copy of MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I've created an ADO.NET, MVC4, EF5 project which has a relationship between an entity and the built in Membership provider's `User`.

I have cloned (using git) my repository to an external server and have set up a database with the same name and run the `.edmx.sql` file created by ADO.NET.

When I run my site on the external server I get the following exception: "Invalid column name 'User_UserId'."

Looking in the database, I can see that Users, Roles, etc. tables have not been created.

What is the best way to do this kind of deployment and rectify my woes?

---

**Update**

So I added the tables in question (Users, Roles, UserRole, Applications) to the database by scripting it from the database on my local machine and still the same error occurs.

This seems to be a problem with the mappings in `System.Web.Security.Membership`.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! Managed to do it. So for anyone else with the same problem - try this:

1. Create a new DB on the external server
2. Run the `.edmx.sql` file on that DB
3. Change the connection string to your server's name
4. Run the site locally - this will create the Users, Roles, etc. tables